# How to cancel a child task if parent times out?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

The following code runs 2 tasks simultaneously, both with a set timeout.

The tier task (parent) has an overall timout value, which when reached, terminates the process.

Within the tier task, a number of node tasks (child) are looped syncronously, so task 1 must complete before moving on to task 2 etc.

If a child task fails to complete within a time frame, it is timed out and the next child task is run.

If the parent task reaches it's timeout, the process stops, however currently the outstanding child task remains running in the background. Child tasks are third-party web services, and if possible I would like to terminate them for cleanliness.

I've taken a look at the microsoft example but am struggling to make it work with my own code.

In short, if the parent terminates, which it can only do via a timeout or exception, I need to cancel the child currently running inseide the loop.

Anyone know how this is achieved.

```
public int NestedTask(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> nodes)
{
    int parentTimeout = 20 * 1000;
    int childTimeout = 2 * 1000;

        var tier = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (var n in nodes)
            {
                var node = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(n.Value * 1000);
                    return 1;
                });

                // If we get the result we return it, else we wait
                if (node.Wait(childTimeout))
                {
                    return node.Result;
                }
            }

            // return timeout node here;
            return -1;
        });

        if (!tier.Wait(parentTimeout))
        {
            // The child will continue on running though.
            ** CANCEL SINGLE CHILD ***
            return -2;
        }
        else if (tier.Exception != null)
        {
            // We have an error
        }

        return tier.Result;
    }
```

Comment: Could your question be formulated "How to cancel a task"? That seems to be what you want.

Comment: See here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx. In a nutshell you have to pass the task a cancellation token and call cancel on that.

Comment: @usr - well its a little more than that - need to idenify the child task and then cancel it.

Comment: Store a reference to the task somewhere where you can retrieve it later. Also, you cannot cancel IO tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify in the child task declaration the `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` option ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/attached-and-detached-child-tasks?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

```
var node = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(n.Value * 1000);
    return 1;
}, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
```